# Import (cannot import name 'ResolveInfo' from 'graphql') error when using newest graphene and graphene-django version

Tags: python, django, graphql

I am having some issues with my django app since updating my dependencies.
Here aer my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'graphene_django',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dojo_manager.dojo',
]
```

and my requirements.txt:

```
aniso8601==8.0.0   
asgiref==3.2.3   
Django==3.0.2   
django-cors-headers==3.2.0   
django-filter==2.2.0   
django-graphql-jwt==0.3.0   
djangorestframework==3.11.0   
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0   
graphene==2.1.8   
graphene-django==2.8.0   
graphene-django-extras==0.4.8   
graphql-core==3.0.1   
graphql-relay==3.0.0   
pip-upgrade-outdated==1.5   
pipupgrade==1.5.2   
promise==2.3   
PyJWT==1.7.1   
python-dateutil==2.8.1   
pytz==2019.3   
Rx==3.0.1   
singledispatch==3.4.0.3   
six==1.13.0   
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

I am getting

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ResolveInfo' from 'graphql' (E:\Ben\GitHub-Repos\dojo-manager\env\lib\site-packages\graphql\__init__.py)
```

I am aware of https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/737 and https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/546 , none of which seem to solve it in my case.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: had similar issue when migrating from `graphene-django==2.15` to `graphene-django==3.0.0b7`. the issue was related to another outdated package relying on graphene-django. i fixed it by updating the other one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix it by downgrading `graphql-core==3.0.1`  to `graphql-core<3` (and all the depencencies).

I must have missed the errors when performing `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I had the same problem with `get_introspection_query`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the header

```
from graphql.type import GraphQLResolveInfo as ResolveInfo
# from graphql.execution.base import ResolveInfo
```